# SparkSQL, How to calculate with dynamic time window?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

| performer | event | event_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | event_a | 2022-07-21 |
| C | event_b | 2022-07-20 |
| B | event_c | 2022-07-18 |
| C | event_d | 2022-07-11 |
| A | event_e | 2022-07-12 |
| B | event_f | 2022-07-11 |
| B | event_g | 2022-07-15 |
| B | event_h | 2022-07-14 |
| B | event_i | 2022-07-13 |

Data sample like this

I wonder if a performer has participated in other event within **NEXT** three days after attending an event

like

| performer | event | event_time | count_other_event_in_NEXT_3_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | event_a | 2022-07-21 | 0 |
| C | event_b | 2022-07-20 | 0 |
| B | event_c | 2022-07-18 | 0 |
| C | event_d | 2022-07-11 | 0 |
| A | event_e | 2022-07-12 | 0 |
| B | event_f | 2022-07-11 | 2 |
| B | event_g | 2022-07-15 | 1 |
| B | event_h | 2022-07-14 | 1 |
| B | event_i | 2022-07-13 | 2 |

```sql
-- This sparkSQL can resolve the question if I want calculate **LAST** 3 days
select performer,
    event,
    event_time,
    count(event) 
         over(partition by performer
              order by cast(event_time as timestamp)
              range between interval 3 days preceding and current row
         ) as cnt
from table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x preceding`: x rows before current row. `x following`: x rows after current row.

```
spark.sql("""
    select performer,
    event,
    event_time,
    count(event) 
         over(partition by performer
              order by cast(event_time as timestamp)
              range between current row and interval 3 days following
         )-1 as cnt
from test_table
""").sort('performer', 'event_time').show(100, False)

+---------+-------+----------+---+
|performer|event  |event_time|cnt|
+---------+-------+----------+---+
|A        |event_e|2022-07-12|0  |
|A        |event_a|2022-07-21|0  |
|B        |event_f|2022-07-11|2  |
|B        |event_i|2022-07-13|2  |
|B        |event_h|2022-07-14|1  |
|B        |event_g|2022-07-15|1  |
|B        |event_c|2022-07-18|0  |
|C        |event_d|2022-07-11|0  |
|C        |event_b|2022-07-20|0  |
+---------+-------+----------+---+
```